# Какую кодировку выставить таблице?

Tags: phpmyadmin, mysql

Всем привет, скажите вот я написал программу которая работает с Базой Данных mySQL, так вот когда тестировал на Денвере всё было нормально и по русски, но когда перебрался на хостинг все русские слова стали ?????????????, хотя кодировку не менял. Так вот может надо другую кодировку поставить чтобы русский поддерживался? У меня стоит **cp1250_general_ci**

Comment: 1250 Вам точно не нужна, если русский язык. 1251 возможно. Но так у Вас вопросы, то может быть это из-за того, что база в 1251 (или пусть 1250), а страницы сайта в UTF-8. То есть надо базу сделать в UTF-8, либо страницы в 125x.

Comment: У меня нету сайта, у меня программа - база, всё.

Answer (score 2):

*Кто-то удалил свой ответ, а вместе с ним ушли в горы мои коментарии.*

Вы сказали, что в самой базе на хостинге у вас отображаются знаки вопросов. В phpMyAdmin на хостинге у вас, как я понял, доступ есть. Поэтому создаете БД, "Сравнение" выбираете **utf8_general_ci**. Дамп локальной базы не упаковываете! Заходим на закладку "Экспорт", снимаем внизу, если стоит, галочку "Сохранить как файл" и жмём "Ок". Копируем в появившемся поле весь дамп, идём в phpMyAdmin на хостинге. Выбираем созданную базу, далее на закладку "SQL", вставляем из буфера сохраненный дамп и жмем "Ок". Вот, как бы и всё. Если база на локалке большая, то возможно придётся переносить каждую таблицу по отдельности. И хорошо бы еще до снятия дампа привести все поля в "Сравнение" **utf8_general_ci**.

P.S. А вообще, вопрос звучит хорошо: "*Какую кодировку выставить таблице?*" По самые помидоры вставить )))

Comment: Сделал, эффекта нету,

Answer (score 1):

Если опция выбора кодировки подключения есть в компонентах которые вы используете для подключения к MySQL, то задайте cp1251.

Или, то-же самое, можно сделать через MySQL-команду:

```
SET NAMES cp1251;
```

Answer (score 1):

UTF8 и только UTF8 - всегда и во всем!

Comment: Мне уже минусонули за это...

Comment: Никакие минусочки не разубедят меня. В интернете должен властвовать ютээф8!