# Кодировка таблиц mysql

Tags: phpmyadmin, mysql

Подскажите такой вопрос: когда в mysql заполняю поле русскими буквами, то выводятся знаки вопросов только. Как решить проблему с кодировкой?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Какую кодировку выставить таблице?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/113314/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b5)